# On the quantity $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

In what follows, we let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  Let
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$$
denote the *deficiency* of $x$, and let
$$s(x) = \sigma(x) - x$$
denote the *sum of aliquot/proper divisors* of $x$.  Finally, denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by
$$I(x) = \frac{\sigma(x)}{x}.$$

Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number must have the form $N = q^k n^2$ where $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Since $q$ is prime and $N$ is perfect, we obtain
$$\frac{q+1}{q} \leq I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q-1}$$
so that we get
$$\frac{2(q-1)}{q} < I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} \leq \frac{2q}{q+1}.$$
Using the identity
$$\frac{D(x)}{x} = 2 - I(x)$$
we obtain the bounds
$${q^k}\bigg(\frac{q-2}{q-1}\bigg) < D(q^k) \leq {q^{k-1}}\bigg(q-1\bigg)$$
and
$$\frac{2n^2}{q+1} \leq D(n^2) < \frac{2n^2}{q}.$$
This implies that
$${2q^k n^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{q-2}{(q-1)(q+1)}\bigg) < D(q^k)D(n^2) < {2q^k n^2}\cdot\bigg(\frac{q-1}{q^2}\bigg).$$
Dividing both sides of the last inequality by $2q^k n^2$, we get
$$\frac{q-2}{(q-1)(q+1)} < \frac{D(q^k)D(n^2)}{2q^k n^2} < \frac{q-1}{q^2}.$$
But we know that
$$D(q^k)D(n^2)=2s(q^k)s(n^2),$$
which can be verified by a direct, brute-force computation.
Thus, the fraction in the middle of the last inequality simplifies to
$$\frac{D(q^k)D(n^2)}{2q^k n^2}=\bigg(\frac{s(q^k)}{q^k}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{s(n^2)}{n^2}\bigg)=\bigg(I(q^k) - 1\bigg)\bigg(I(n^2) - 1\bigg) = 3 - \bigg(I(q^k) + I(n^2)\bigg).$$

We therefore finally have the bounds
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{q-1}{q^2}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2) < 3 - \bigg(\frac{q-2}{(q-1)(q+1)}\bigg)$$
which does not improve on the known bounds
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq 3 - \bigg(\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}\bigg).$$
(See this [paper](http://nntdm.net/volume-23-2017/number-3/53-59/) for a proof.)

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS** Is it possible to improve on the bounds for $D(q^k)$ and $D(n^2)$ (where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$) to hopefully produce stronger bounds for $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$?  If so, how could this be done?

Comment: Note that
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{q-1}{q^2}\bigg) \geq \frac{71}{25} = 2.84$$
while
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}\bigg) \geq \frac{57}{20} = 2.85.$$

Comment: FYI, let $f(k):=I(q^k) + I(n^2)$. Then, $f'(k)\lt 0$, so $\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)\lt f(k)\le f(1)$ which is the known bounds. So, I think (1) if you prove $k\not=1$, then you can get an improved upper bound. (2) if you get an improved upper bound, then you can say $k\not=1$. (3) if you prove that there is an integer $N$ such that $k\le N$, then you can get an improved lower bound. (4) if you get an improved lower bound, then you can say that there is an integer $N$ such that $k\le N$. (I'm **not** saying that if you can't improve the bounds for $k$, you can't improve the bounds for $f(k)$.)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @mathlove! You are on a roll! =) Would you mind fleshing out your comments as an actual answer, and include additional details if needed, so that I may be able to upvote and accept? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OP's request, I am converting my comment into an answer.

Let $f(k):=I(q^k) + I(n^2)$.

Then, we have
$$f'(k)=\frac{-( q^{2 k + 2}- 4 q^{2 k + 1}+2 q^{k + 1}   + 2 q^{2 k} - 1) \log(q)}{(q - 1)q^k (q^{k + 1} - 1)^2}$$
which is negative, so we see that $f(k)$ is decreasing.

It follows that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)\lt f(k)\le f(1)\tag1$$
which is the known bounds
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq 3 - \bigg(\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}\bigg)\tag2$$

So, I think that this means the following :

- If you prove that $k\not=1$, then you can get an improved upper bound for $f(k)$.
- If you get an improved upper bound for $f(k)$, then you can say that $k\not=1$.
- If you prove that there is an integer $a$ such that $k\le a$, then you can get an improved lower bound for $f(k)$.
- If you get an improved lower bound for $f(k)$, then you can say that there is an integer $a$ such that $k\le a$.

(I'm **not** saying that if you can't improve the bounds for $k$, you can't improve the bounds for $f(k)$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove!  I noticed that you used the same variable for the upper bound of $k$ as my variable for the odd perfect number $N$.  We do agree, however, that the inequality
$$k \leq N = q^k n^2$$
is trivial, do we not?  =)

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Thanks for noticing it. That's not what I meant. I should have used a different variable. I've edited the answer.

Comment: My apologies for the bother @mathlove, but I have been trying to prove your third and fourth assertions, and I just realized that I could not reproduce your proofs.  Would you mind sharing a sketch of your argument?

Comment: Okay @mathlove, just now I used WolframAlpha to get the partial fraction decomposition of $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ and obtained
$$\frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \frac{1}{q^k (q - 1)} + \frac{2(q - 1)}{q(q^{k+1} - 1)}.$$
I am unable to proceed further, since I do not know how to handle the negative summand.

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : The key is the fact that $f(k)$ is decreasing. For the third, if you prove that there is an integer $a$ such that $k\le a$, then, considering the graph of $y=f(k)$, we see that $f(a)$ is an improved lower bound. For the fourth, if you get an improved lower bound $g(q)$, then from the above fact, we see that there is only one $k=k_0$ such that $f(k)=g(q)$. Then, we have $k\le \lceil k_0\rceil$.

Comment: Thank you for your further comments, @mathlove.  For your proof of the fourth implication, I noticed you used the variable $q$ (for the special prime?) as an argument for the lower bound $g$.  Does this mean that the lower bound obtained depends on $q$?

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to work backwards from
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq 3 - \bigg(\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}\bigg).$$
This can be rewritten as
$$\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)} \leq 3 - \bigg(I(q^k) + I(n^2)\bigg) = \frac{D(q^k)D(n^2)}{2q^k n^2} < \frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}.$$
We also have
$$\frac{2n^2}{q+1} \leq D(n^2) < \frac{2n^2}{q},$$
which we can rewrite as
$$q < \frac{2n^2}{D(n^2)} \leq q + 1.$$
We therefore obtain
$$\frac{q-1}{q+1} = \frac{q(q-1)}{q(q+1)} < \bigg(\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{D(n^2)}\bigg) \leq \frac{D(q^k)}{q^k} < \bigg(\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{2n^2}{D(n^2)}\bigg) \leq \frac{(q+1)(q-2)}{q(q-1)},$$
which implies that
$$\frac{q-1}{q+1} < 2 - I(q^k) < \frac{(q+1)(q-2)}{q(q-1)},$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{q^2 - q + 2}{q^2 - q} = 2 - \bigg(\frac{(q+1)(q-2)}{q(q-1)}\bigg) < I(q^k) < 2 - \bigg(\frac{q-1}{q+1}\bigg) = \frac{q+3}{q+1}.$$
Note that both bounds do not improve on the currently known
$$\frac{q+1}{q} \leq I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q-1}.$$