# Is it possible to improve on the bound $D(q^k) < \varphi(q^k)$ if $k > 1$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

The problem is as is in the title:

> Is it possible to improve on the bound $$D(q^k) < \varphi(q^k)$$ if $k > 1$?

Here, $q$ is a prime number and $k$ is a positive integer.  The (deficiency) function $D(x)$ is defined as follows:
$$D(x) = 2x - \sigma(x)$$
where $\sigma(x)$ is the classical sum of divisors of $x$.

Of course, $\varphi(x)$ is just the Euler totient function of $x$.  Finally, let $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ be the abundancy index of $x$.

**MY PROOF FOR THE BOUND**

Since in general we just have $k \geq 1$, we have
$$\frac{q+1}{q} = I(q) \leq I(q^k)$$
from which we get
$$\frac{D(q^k)}{q^k} = 2 - I(q^k) \leq 2 - \frac{q+1}{q} = \frac{q-1}{q} = \frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k},$$
whereby we finally obtain
$$D(q^k) \leq \varphi(q^k).$$

So if $k > 1$, then I just get
$$I(q) < I(q^k),$$
right?  Proceeding similarly as before, I obtain
$$D(q^k) < \varphi(q^k).$$

Here is my specific question:

> Will it be possible to come up with a tighter upper bound than $\varphi(q^k)$ for $D(q^k)$ when $k > 1$?

**Edited (in response to a comment on November 5, 2020)**

The reason I need a bound for $D(q^k)$ when $k>1$ is because of this [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3888565).

Comment: Since $q^k$ is a prime power, there are explicit expressions for $\sigma (q^k)$ (and also $\phi(q^k)$), and so one exists for $D(q^k)$ as well:
$$D(q^k) = 2q^k - \frac {q^{k+1}-1}{q-1} = \frac {q^{k+1}-2q^k+1}{q-1} = q^k - q^{k-1} - q^{k-2}-\dots-1$$
 Why do you need a bound?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @player3236.  The reason I need a bound is because of [this closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888565).

Comment: Still, for $k=2$, $D(q^2) = q^2 - q - 1$ while $\varphi(q^2) = q^2-q$, showing that it is the tightest upper bound (for $k=2$). Otherwise, as shown in the previous comment, you can still have wiggle room of $q^{k-2} + q^{k-3} + \dots + q$.

Comment: If $k\equiv q\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then we have $D(q^k)\le \varphi(q^k)-\frac{5^{k-1}-1}{4}$ and $D(q^k)\le \varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}$. So we have $3-\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{5^{k-1}-1}{4}\bigg)\lt I(q^k)+I(n^2)$ and $3-\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}\bigg)\lt I(q^k)+I(n^2)$. But I think that these are not better lower bounds for $I(q^k)+I(n^2)$ than $3-\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}$.

Comment: Thank you for your last comment, @mathlove!  Can you add that into your response below, so that I may be able to accept your answer?  I have already added the necessary context to the OP, in response to [player3236](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/435724)'s comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$f(k,q):=\varphi(q^k)-D(q^k)=q^{k-1}(q-1)-\bigg(2q^k-\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}\bigg)=\frac{q^{k-1}-1}{q-1}$$

Then we have

$$\frac{\partial f(k,q)}{\partial q}=\frac{((q-1)(k-2)-1)q^k+q^2}{(q - 1)^2 q^2}$$
which is non-negative.

So, we have
$$f(k,q)\ge f(k,2),$$

i.e.
$$\color{red}{D(q^k)\le \varphi(q^k)-(2^{k-1}-1)}$$

---

**Added** :

If $k\equiv q\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then we have $$D(q^k)\le \varphi(q^k)-\frac{5^{k-1}-1}{4}$$ and $$D(q^k)\le\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}$$ So we have $$3−\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{5^{k-1}-1}{4}\bigg)\lt I(q^k)+I(n^2)$$ and $$3−\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}\bigg)\lt I(q^k)+I(n^2)$$ But I think that these are not better lower bounds for $I(q^k)+I(n^2)$ than $3−\dfrac{q−2}{q(q−1)}$.

Comment: Gladly accepting your answer now, @mathlove!  I hope you do not mind me correcting your algebraic mistakes.

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Thanks for correcting typos.

Comment: Hi there, @mathlove.  Can you double-check the lower bound
$$3-\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k) - \frac{q^4 - 1}{q - 1}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2)?$$
When $k=1$, I am getting
$$3-\bigg(\frac{q-1}{q^2}\bigg)+\frac{q^4 - 1}{q^2 (q - 1)} < I(q^k) + I(n^2),$$
which I think improves upon
$$3-\bigg(\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2),$$
since the inequality
$$3-\bigg(\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}\bigg) < 3-\bigg(\frac{q-1}{q^2}\bigg)+\frac{q^4 - 1}{q^2 (q - 1)}$$
is satisfied by $q \geq 5$.

Comment: Here is the [WolframAlpha computational verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3+-+%28%28q-1%29%2Fq%5E2%29+%2B+%28%28q%5E4+-+1%29%2F%28q%5E2+%28q+-+1%29%29%29+%3E+3+-+%28%28q+-+2%29%2F%28q%28q+-+1%29%29%29) for the above inequality.

Comment: Additionally, the *purported new lower bound* for $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ can be re-expressed as
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > 3-\bigg(\frac{q-1}{q^2}\bigg)+\frac{q^4 - 1}{q^2 (q - 1)}=\frac{q^3 + 4q^2 + 2}{q^2}=q+4+\frac{2}{q^2}>q+4 \geq 9,$$
**contradicting** $I(q^k)+I(n^2)<3$ ([Corollary 10, page 5 (Dris, 2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf)).

Comment: Blimey!  I forgot that we **ought** to be considering $k>1$ in this question.

Comment: This is the [WolframAlpha computational verification](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3-%28%28q-1%29%2F%28q%5E2%29%29%2B%28%28q%5E4+-+1%29%2F%28%28q%5E%28k%2B1%29%29%28q+-+1%29%29%29%3C3-%28%28q-2%29%2F%28q%28q-1%29%29%29) for the inequality
$$3-\bigg(\frac{q-1}{q^2}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{q^4 - 1}{q^{k+1} (q - 1)}\bigg) < 3-\bigg(\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}\bigg),$$
which shows that it is true when $k \geq 5$, an inequality which holds when $k>1$ since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : The LHS of the inequality in your last comment is wrong. We see that $$3−\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}\bigg)\lt 3−\dfrac{q−2}{q(q−1)}$$holds for $k\ge 5$ since we have$$\bigg(3−\dfrac{q−2}{q(q−1)}\bigg)-\bigg(3−\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}\bigg)\bigg)=\frac{q^{k-1}-q^4+1}{q^{k+1}(q-1)}\gt 0$$So, $3−\frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}\bigg)$ is not a better lower bound for $I(q^k)+I(n^2)$ than $3−\dfrac{q−2}{q(q−1)}$.

Comment: I apologize, but I do not see how the LHS of my last comment is incorrect, @mathlove.  Is it not the case that
$$\frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k} = \frac{q-1}{q}?$$

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : We have here $k\ge 5$, don't we?

Comment: Well yes, we do have $k \geq 5$.  Is it not the case that
$$\frac{\varphi(q^k)}{q^k}=\frac{q-1}{q}$$
for all $k$?  (Kindly refer to the [Wikipedia page for Euler's totient function, Value of phi for a prime power argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Computing_Euler%27s_totient_function).)

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Ah, sorry, I didn't noticed that. You are right. I thought that you substituted $k=1$ into the first $k$. Anyway, see my comment. You don't need to use WolframAlpha here.