# Revisiting questions 3888565 and 3894925

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

I would like to revisit these two questions:

[Is it possible to improve on the bound $D(q^k) < \varphi(q^k)$ if $k>1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3894925)

[On the quantity $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888565)

Here, $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the classical *sum of divisors* of $x$, $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the *deficiency* of $x$, $\varphi(x)$ is the *Euler totient function* of $x$, and $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ is the *abundancy index* of $x$.

In the OP of the second question, the following lower bound is derived:
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{q-1}{q^2}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2).$$

In the [accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3895067/28816) to the first question, MSE user [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967) gives the following improved lower bound, under the assumption that $k>1$:
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{q-1}{q^2}\bigg) + \bigg(\frac{q^4 - 1}{q^{k+1} (q - 1)}\bigg) = 3 - \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k) - \frac{q^4 - 1}{q - 1}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2).$$

Here are my two questions:

> **(1)** How does one prove the improved lower bound given by mathlove?

> **(2)** Is the improved lower bound given by mathlove already "best-possible", in the sense of being obtainable via the $D(q^k)$-route?

(Note that I am already aware of the lower bound
$$3 - \bigg(\frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2),$$
which **does not** answer *Question* **(2)**, because while this latter lower bound improves on mathlove's result, to the best of my knowledge it is not obtainable via the $D(q^k)$-route.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer to the question **(1)**.

Let
$$f(k):=\varphi(q^k)-D(q^k)=q^{k-1}(q-1)-\bigg(2q^k-\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}\bigg)=\frac{q^{k-1}-1}{q-1}$$
Then, we see that $f(k)$ is increasing.

So, if $k\gt 1$ and $k\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then we have $f(k)\ge f(5)=\dfrac{q^{4}-1}{q-1}$ which is equivalent to
$$D(q^k)\le\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}$$
Using
$$D(n^2) < \frac{2n^2}{q}$$
we get
$$D(q^k)D(n^2) < \frac{2n^2}{q}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}\bigg)$$
Dividing the both sides by $2q^k n^2$, we obtain
$$\frac{D(q^k)D(n^2)}{2q^k n^2} < \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}\bigg)$$
which can be written as
$$3 - \bigg(I(q^k) + I(n^2)\bigg) < \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}\bigg)$$

We therefore finally have
$$3 - \frac{1}{q^{k+1}}\bigg(\varphi(q^k)-\frac{q^4-1}{q-1}\bigg) < I(q^k) + I(n^2) $$