# On a conjectured upper bound for $k=\nu_q(N)$, if $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, conjectures, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $N=q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Denote the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$ as $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ where $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.  (For example, when $M$ is perfect, we have $\sigma(M)=2M$ and $I(M)=\sigma(M)/M=2$.  The smallest example of an *even perfect number* is $6$.  It is currently unknown if there are any *odd perfect numbers*.)

Fix a positive integer $a$.

We have
$$k \leq a \iff I(q^k) \leq I(q^a) \iff \frac{2}{I(q^a)} \leq \frac{2}{I(q^k)}=I(n^2)$$
$$\iff I(q^k) \leq I(q^a) < \frac{2}{I(q^a)} \leq I(n^2),$$
since
$$I(q^a) = \frac{q^{a+1} - 1}{q^a (q - 1)} < \frac{q}{q-1} \leq \frac{5}{4} < \sqrt{2}.$$
Therefore, we get
$$k \leq a \iff \Bigg[I(q^k) - I(q^a)\Bigg]\Bigg[I(n^2) - I(q^a)\Bigg] \leq 0$$
$$\iff 2 + (I(q^a))^2 \leq I(q^a)\Bigg[I(q^k) + I(n^2)\Bigg].$$
We thus obtain the following proposition:

**PROPOSITION** If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $k \leq a$ holds if and only if
$$I(q^a) + \frac{2}{I(q^a)} \leq I(q^k) + I(n^2).$$

**ALTERNATIVE PROOF OF THE PROPOSITION** Note that the same proposition can be proved by using the fact that
$$f(k) = I(q^k) + I(n^2) = I(q^k) + \frac{2}{I(q^k)}$$
is a decreasing function of $k$.  (See [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967)'s [answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3890892/28816).)

But
$$I(q^a) + \frac{2}{I(q^a)} = \frac{q^{a+1} - 1}{q^a (q - 1)} + \frac{2q^a(q - 1)}{q^{a+1} - 1} = \frac{3q^{2a+2} - 4q^{2a+1} + 2q^{2a} - 2q^{a+1} + 1}{q^a (q - 1)(q^{a+1} - 1)},$$
whose partial fraction decomposition, per [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Partial%20fraction%20decomposition%20of%20%28%28q%5E%28a%2B1%29%20-%201%29%2F%28q%5Ea%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%29%20%2B%20%28%282q%5Ea%20%28q%20-%201%29%29%2F%28q%5E%28a%2B1%29%20-%201%29%29), is
$$\frac{2(q - 1)}{q(q^{a+1} - 1)} - \frac{1}{q^a (q - 1)} + \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)},$$
where of course
$$\frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} < I(q^k) + I(n^2)$$
holds unconditionally (i.e. even if we do not have the condition $k \leq a$).

So here is my:

**INITIAL QUESTION**

> Does the inequality
> $$\frac{2(q - 1)}{q(q^{a+1} - 1)} > \frac{1}{q^a (q - 1)}$$
> hold for all special primes $q$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose to the contrary that there exists a special prime $q$ such that
$$\frac{1}{q^a (q - 1)} \geq \frac{2(q - 1)}{q(q^{a+1} - 1)}.$$

This last inequality is equivalent to
$$q^{a+2} - q \geq 2{q^a}(q - 1)^2 = 2{q^a}(q^2 - 2q + 1) = 2q^{a+2} - 4q^{a+1} + 2q^a$$
$$\iff 0 \geq q^{a+2} - 4q^{a+1} + 2q^a + q = q^{a+1} (q - 4) + 2q^a + q > 0,$$
which is a *contradiction*.

**FINAL QUESTION**

> Does the contradiction suffice to prove that $k \leq a$?

Comment: I think that the answer to the final question is no. If you want to prove $A - B + C\leq D$, then $A\gt B$ and $C\lt D$ are not sufficient where $A= \dfrac{2(q - 1)}{q(q^{a+1} - 1)},B= \dfrac{1}{q^a (q - 1)},C= \dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)}$ and $D= I(q^k) + I(n^2)$.

Comment: Please write that out as an actual answer, @mathlove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer to the final question is no.

If you want to prove $$A−B+C\le D$$
then $$A>B\qquad\text{and}\qquad C<D$$
are not sufficient where $$A=\frac{2(q−1)}{q(q^{a+1}−1)},\qquad B=\frac{1}{q^a(q−1)},
$$
$$C=\frac{3q^2−4q+2}{q(q−1)},\qquad D=I(q^k)+I(n^2)$$